# How to iterate through a supermarket website and getting the product name and prices?

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Im trying to obtain all the product name and prices from all the categories from a supermarket website, all the tutorials that i have found do it just for one const url, i need to iterate through all of them. So far i have got this

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="product-nonfood-page"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1/div');
    const text2 = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const name = await text2.jsonValue();

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="product-nonfood-page"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/em[2]/strong/text()');
    const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const price = await text.jsonValue();

    console.log({name,price});

    await browser.close();
}

scrapeProduct('https://www.jumbo.com.ar/gaseosa-sprite-sin-azucar-lima-limon-1-25-lt/p');
```

which works just for one. Im using nodejs and puppeteer. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `for...of` loop, using a single browser instance and a single page so that the scraper might not overload the server:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    const urls = [
      'https://www.jumbo.com.ar/gaseosa-sprite-sin-azucar-lima-limon-1-25-lt/p',
      // ...
    ];

    for (const url of urls) {
      await page.goto(url);

      const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="product-nonfood-page"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1/div');
      const text2 = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
      const name = await text2.jsonValue();

      const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="product-nonfood-page"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/em[2]/strong/text()');
      const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
      const price = await text.jsonValue();

      console.log({name,price});
    }

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I really like this approach, is there a way to get all the urls of all the products and store them in the array? Or would that be too slow/too memory consuming?

Comment: Usually a scraping is either slow (if reqests are consecutive as in the example above) or hogging memory/CPU and (often) abusing server (if all or some reqests are parallel). If you use consecutive reqests, you can store any ammount of URLs in an  array and process them one by one. If you need speed up, you can try [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of urls and `forEach`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const urls = [ 'https://www.jumbo.com.ar/gaseosa-sprite-sin-azucar-lima-limon-1-25-lt/p' ];

urls.forEach(scrapeProduct);

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="product-nonfood-page"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1/div');
    const text2 = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const name = await text2.jsonValue();

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="product-nonfood-page"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/em[2]/strong/text()');
    const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const price = await text.jsonValue();

    console.log({name,price});

    await browser.close();
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer. What will happen if you have a hundred URLs in `urls` array? They will all run at once.

Comment: @Vaviloff, yes, that is correct. They will all run at once.